# Error : cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization attempted to call method 'value'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have written something like below. onclick of div with id "PLUS" I
 am getting the following error:

`cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization attempted to call method 'value'`

```html
<div id="PLUS" class="PLUS"></div>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".slider").slider({
      animate: true,
      range: "min",
      value: 18,
      min: 18,
      max: 70,
      step: 1,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#slider-result").html(ui.value);
        document.getElementById(findElement('ageId')).value = ui.value;
      },
      //this updates the hidden form field so we can submit the data using a form
      change: function(event, ui) {
        $('#hidden').attr('value', ui.value);
      }
    });

    $(".PLUS").click(function() {
      var value = $("#slider-result").slider("value"),
        step = $("#slider-result").slider("option", "step");
      $("#slider-result").slider("value", value + step);
    });

  });
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please share the rest of necessary HTML such as elements `".slider"`, `"#slider-result"` etc

Answer (score 5):

If we check error in detail you will notice that it says you are trying to call the `value` method before the initialization of **slider plugin**.

**Reason:**

Actually JavaScript is an interpreted language, and it doesn't wait for first command to execute and finish. That's why your     `$(".slider").slider({` and `$(".PLUS").click(function() {` lines run at same time and the error occurs.

**Solution:**

You can put your code in `setTimeout` function here is an example given below.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".slider").slider({
      animate: true,
      range: "min",
      value: 18,
      min: 18,
      max: 70,
      step: 1,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#slider-result").html(ui.value);
        document.getElementById(findElement('ageId')).value = ui.value;
      },
      //this updates the hidden form field so we can submit the data using a form
      change: function(event, ui) {
        $('#hidden').attr('value', ui.value);
      }
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
      $(".PLUS").click(function() {
        var value = $("#slider-result").slider("value"),
          step = $("#slider-result").slider("option", "step");
        $("#slider-result").slider("value", value + step);
      });
    },200); // 200 = 0.2 seconds = 200 miliseconds

  });
</script>
```

I hope this will help you/someone.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

You have used `$(".slider").slider()` at the time of initializing and 
`$("#slider-result").slider()` at the time of getting the value some plugins work on selector you have used at the time of init, so try that.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused because `$("#slider-result")`  is not the element initialized as slider and you're trying to execute slider widget methods on it instead of `$(".slider")` which is the actual slider.

Your code should be

```js
$(".PLUS").click(function() {
  var value = $(".slider").slider("value"),
    step = $(".slider").slider("option", "step");
  $("#slider-result").text(value + step);
 //---- maybe you'll need to ----^----  parseInt() the values here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem.
your block here

```
$(".PLUS").click(function() {
     var value = $("#slider-result").slider("value")
      , step = $("#slider-result").slider("option", "step");
      $("#slider-result").slider("value", value + step);
});
```

just keep it under

```
create: function( event, ui ) {}
```

ie.

```
create: function( event, ui ) {
    $(".PLUS").click(function() {
      var value = ui.value;
      , step = $("#slider-result").slider("option", "step");
      $("#slider-result").slider("value", value + step);
  });
}
```

hope this works.

Comment: The event handler is below the script that initializes slider and slider initialization is not asynchronous so it'll be added only after slider is created, that's not the problem. By the way you have syntax error in your answer `var value = ui.value; , step`

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to achieve this is to use the event from the ON function from the slider library to get the value. Ex:

```
slider.on('slideStop', function(ev) {
    let value= ev.value; //try ev if you want to see all
    console.log(value);
})
```

Regards