# retrieve jquery slider value in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a jquery slider function and other javascript functions
i would like to retrieve the value of the jquery slider in javascript but i cant
if i do this

```
var s=$( "#slider_placement" ).slider( "value" );
```

in javascript it says error

```
Error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'value'
```

i tried doing this in java script

```
var h = $('#custom-handle').text();
console.log(h);
```

but the console shows me empty result

here is the jquery slider code

```
$( function() {
    var handle = $( "#custom-handle_wins" );
    $( "#slider_wins" ).slider({
        min:1,
        max:10,
        value:1,
        step:1,
        create: function() {
            handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
        },
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            handle.text( ui.value );
            var s=ui.value;
            document.getElementById("no_wins").innerHTML='Number of Wins: ' + ui.value;
        }
    });
    s=$( "#slider_wins" ).slider( "value" );
    document.getElementById("no_wins").innerHTML='Number of Wins: ' + s;

} );
```

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your HTML, I'd guess that the javascript is executing before the whole page is finished loading.  You could try wrapping your `slider("value")` code in a `document.ready()` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error : cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization attempted to call method 'value'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601565/error-cannot-call-methods-on-slider-prior-to-initialization-attempted-to-call)